# Magento 2.2.2 How to implement Backend (Customizable Options) logic in custom module

Tags: magento2.2.2, customizable-options

I am trying to implement **customizable options** like logic in my **custom module**. What I wanna do is to create an **add option** button, and upon clicking this button same gird will show. You can see in the below pic[image]

I want to create same thing as in this image, but I will change fields in this grid according to my requirement.

I am not able to create this thing, I have tried finding it in core, but don't know how it is implemented in the core.

Comment: This form defined in the `Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions` class. For your purpose use the `ui/dynamic-rows` components. May be this information can help you.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau thanks, but how to implement this file in my custom module.